# Retrieve a record from session object in nodejs

Tags: node.js, session, express

Am new to `nodejs` here and I have below data in my `session` which will be available during page post

```
{"lstDetails":
     [
      {"ID":"FFSDER2da2411cDSs12CGh21",
       "FirstName":"Test",
       "LastName":"Data",
       "DOB":"8/15/1921 12:00:00 AM",
       "AddressLine1":"Test Address Line 1",
       "AddressLine2":"",
       "City":"FakeCity",
       "State":"ST",
       "Zip":"41511",
       "PID":0,
       "EmailID":"SC4239925@FakeEmail.com",
       "Gender":"1",
       "WorkPhone":"",
       "OtherPhone":"5555555555",
       "ICarier":
                  {"ICName":null,
                  "IGName":null,
                  "IGNum":null
                  }
       },
       {"ID":"DS24DASD5da21afd56D4#2!",
       "FirstName":"Test2",
       "LastName":"Data2",
       "DOB":"8/15/1921 12:00:00 AM",
       "AddressLine1":"Test2 Address Line 1",
       "AddressLine2":"",
       "City":"FakeCity2",
       "State":"ST2",
       "Zip":"41511",
       "PID":0,
       "EmailID":"SC4239925@FakeEmail.com",
       "Gender":"1",
       "WorkPhone":"",
       "OtherPhone":"5555555555",
       "ICarier":
                  {"ICName":null,
                  "IGName":null,
                  "IGNum":null
                  }
       }
     ]
}
```

and the above detail will be stored in `req.Session`. How can search for particular data from above `session` object using `ID` and fetch a particular record? I have went on through net, but unfortunately did not find any useful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either filter or map to search through the array to find the object (node) you want.

Simplified example:

```
var myArray = [{
  "ID":"FFSDER2da2411cDSs12CGh21",
  "FirstName":"Test",
  "LastName":"Data"
},
{
  "ID":"DS24DASD5da21afd56D4#2!",
  "FirstName":"Test2",
  "LastName":"Data2"
}];

var result = myArray.filter(function(f) { 
  if (f.ID === 'FFSDER2da2411cDSs12CGh21') { 
    return f; 
  } 
});
```

Results in a result array with one object, filtered on ID. You can filter by comparing on part of string, RegEx, etc.

Comment: Can make a custom function for filtering that takes id as paramter. For ex. `function idFilter(arr, id){ return arr.filter(function (f){ if (f.id == id) return f; }}; idFilter(myArray, id);`

Comment: No jQuery needed in either Sami or my suggestion. Just plain old Javascript.

Comment: when I do `req.session.searchData` it gives me the object posted in question. I cannot pass the object right.. I mean I need to extract `lstDetail` separately but when I tried `req.session.searchData["lstDetail"]` its giving undefined and because of which above method is throwing error.. Do you know how to extract that `lstDetail`?

Comment: lstDetails is a javascript property in the object you used in your question. It should be accessible as such. req.session.searchData.lstDetail. Check it in your debug environment.

Comment: anyways.. I am trying but am not able to get it.. I will accept this answer as this way I can retrieve my data.. Thanks for the input.. :)